# How to project a line on a surfaceplot?

Tags: python, 3d, interpolation

I Have a surface plot created from point data stored in a CSV file. If I want to project a line (which is floating above the surface) on the surface created in 3D. What is the method?

I have tried a code from the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29549905/pylab-3d-scatter-plots-with-2d-projections-of-plotted-data) for projecting a line on xy-xz-yz plane.
I can see that it is projecting the endpoint of line on the xy-xz-yz plane.

If I want to project on the surface created with point data. I don't have an equation of the surface. I have created with point data available.

Here is a mockup image of what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]
I have generated a curved surface with given scattered points stored in a CSV file. Now I want to project the line on top of the surface(red line) to the surface(as a green line).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets build a generic MCVE, first we import required packages:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import matplotlib.tri as mtri
np.random.seed(123456) # Fix the random seed
```

Now we generate a collection of 3D points for a surface `S` (notice it is an irregular mesh):

```
NS = 100
Sx = np.random.uniform(low=-1., high=1., size=(NS,))
Sy = np.random.uniform(low=-1., high=1., size=(NS,))
Sz = -(Sx**2 + Sy**2) + 0.1*np.random.normal(size=(NS,))
```

And a parametric curve `P`:

```
NP = 100
t = np.linspace(-1, 1, NP)
Px = t
Py = t**2 - 0.5
Pz = t**3 + 1
```

The key to solve your problem is [`LinearNDInterpolator`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator.html) which performs a piecewise linear interpolation in N dimensions:

```
PSz = interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator(list(zip(Sx, Sy)), Sz)(list(zip(Px,Py)))
```

There is just the need to reshape data to fit the method signature from separate vectors to matrix of shape `(Nsample,Ndims)` which can be translated to:

```
list(zip(Sx, Sy))
```

We can check the data from the top:

```
tri = mtri.Triangulation(Sx, Sy)
fig, axe = plt.subplots()
axe.plot(Sx, Sy, '+')
axe.plot(Px, Py)
axe.triplot(tri, linewidth=1, color='gray')
axe.set_aspect('equal')
axe.grid()
```

[image]

The complete 3D result is shown bellow:

```
axe = plt.axes(projection='3d')
axe.plot_trisurf(tri, Sz, cmap='jet', alpha=0.5)
axe.plot(Px, Py, Pz)
axe.plot(Px, Py, PSz, linewidth=2, color='black')
axe.scatter(Sx, Sy, Sz)
axe.view_init(elev=25, azim=-45)
```

[image]

```
axe.view_init(elev=75, azim=-45)
```

[image]